# After add new row 'timepicker' does not work. How can fix it?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group addTable" style="padding:10px 10px">
 <div id="addrow"><input name="button" type="button" class="add-holidays-row  btn-md btn-primary pull-left" value="Add New Holiday Row"/></div>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class="table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
 <tbody id="addHolidaysRow"><tr>
  <td align="center" class="delete-holidays-row"  title="Remove"><i style="color:#FF0000; cursor:pointer;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></td><td><textarea name="events[]" id="remarks" cols="" rows="1"></textarea</td>
    <td><input name="start_date[]" type="text" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" autocomplete="off" id=""></td>
  <td><input name="end_date[]" type="text" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" autocomplete="off" id=""  ></td>
  <td>
  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
   <input  name="start_time[]" class="form-control timepickerinput" type="text">
   <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i> </span> 
  </div>
  </td>
 <td>
  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
  <input  name="end_time[]" class="form-control timepickerinput" type="text">
  <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i> </span> 
   </div>
  </td>
   <td>
   <select name="status[]" id="" class="form-control" >
   <option value="Active" selected="selected">Active</option>
   <option value="Inactive" >Inactive</option>
   </select>
   </td>
  </tr></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   $('.timepickerinput').timepicker({
      minuteStep: 1,
      showSeconds: true,
      showMeridian: true,
      disableFocus: true,
      defaultTime: false
    }).on('focus', function() {
      $('#timepicker1').timepicker('showWidget');
    }).next().on(ace.click_event, function() {
      $(this).prev().focus();
    });
```

Time Picker works only first row. When I add instant new row new time picker does not work without first row. How can fix it?

Comment: The code is working for me. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: It's work also for me but this work only firs input field than when add instant more input field they are does not work (without first input field). please help me how i can  fix it. @James

Comment: did you include the jquery link ?

Comment: yaa.. i include jquery link. if i don't include jquery link does not work its first row/first input fields. @jothi